# Why gravitational potential concept used in physics

Tags: energy, gravity, potential

As gravitational potential energy is well good to tell us everything, but why we need to use gravitational potential

Comment: because we use classical mechanics equations in order to calculate orbits etc?

Comment: Gravitational potential makes the description of the field depend only because of the source mass. For gravitational potential energy, the test mass magnitude is multiplied to this potential.

Comment: Also higher gravitational potential means less time dilation, which could be an important factor.